# Rails3 and safe nl2br !

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a system for the users to be able to post comments.

The comments are grasped into a textarea.

My problem is to format the comments with br tag to replace \n

In fact, i could do something like that

`s.gsub(/\n/, '<br />')`

But the xss protection including in rails escapes br tags.

So i could do this

`s.gsub(/\n/, '<br />').html_safe`

But then, all the tags are accepted even script.... causing a big security problem

So my question is : how to format text with br safely ?

Thanks

EDIT:
For now, i have add this

```
  def sanitaze
    self.gsub(/(<.*?>)/, '')
  end

  def nl2br
    self.sanitaze.gsub(/\n/, '<br />').html_safe
  end
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As Ryan Bigg suggested `simple_format` is the best tool for the job: it's 'l safe' and much neater than other solutions.

so for @var:

```
<%= simple_format(@var) %>
```

If you need to sanitize the text to get rid of HTML tags, you should do this *before* passing it to `simple_format`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Comment: Works like a charm, thaks a lot to you and Ryan for the suggestion!

Comment: `simple_format` might often be the best solution, but it puts <p> tags around and (sometimes) inside your text, so I ended up using `<%= raw(h(comment.text).gsub(/\n/,"<br />\n")) %>`.

Comment: @amoebe You can set `:wrapper_tag` to `nil`. `:wrapper_tag - String representing the wrapper tag, defaults to "p"`.

Comment: @Chloe doesn't seem to work for me, just outputs empty tags then: `simple_format("a\n b\n\n c", {}, wrapper_tag: nil) => "<>a\n<br /> b</>\n\n<> c</>"`

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can figure to go about this is using the sanitize method to strip all but the BR tag we want.

Assume that we have `@var` with the content `"some\ntext"`:

Trying `<%= @var.gsub(/\n/, '<br />') %>` doesn't work.

Trying `<%= h @var.gsub(/\n/, '<br />').html_safe %>` doesn't work and is unsafe.

Trying `<%= sanitize(@var.gsub(/\n/, '<br />'), :tags => %w(br) %>` WORKS.

I haven't tested this very well, but it allows the BR tag to work, and replaced a dummy script alert I added with white space, so it seems to be doing its job. If anyone else has an idea or can say if this is a safe solution, please do.

Update:

Another idea suggested by Jose Valim:

`<%= h(@var).gsub(/\n/, '<br />') %>` Works

Comment: Thanks for your contribution :)
I gonna try this :)

Comment: The "another idea" did what I needed. `simple_format` wrapped everything in a `<p></p>` NOTE: I needed to add .html_safe (rails 3.2)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [what I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29669181/52499):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def nl2br s
    sanitize(s, tags: []).gsub(/\n/, '<br>').html_safe
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, instead of and/or in conjunction with others suggested, is simply using CSS with the rule `white-space: pre-wrap;` for the element where you render the text.

It will cause whitespace like newlines and multiple spaces to be rendered instead of ignored.

It is very much like the default rendering of the html `<pre>` tag, but without the default monospace font and lack of line wrapping.