# Rails: Place text on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text

Ruby doesn't seem to have any method to convert my text to HTML before putting it on the page, so newlines do not appear. What am I missing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844358/rails3-and-safe-nl2br

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [simple_format](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) view helper is typically a good starting point for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks; it works great, but what do you mean by saying it's a starting point?

Comment: When you will come to the point, where newlines aren't enough for formatting, then check stuph like RedCloth, BlueCloth, RDiscount, etc.