# Rails 3. simple_format do not wrap result in paragraph tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make simple_format not wrap the returned value in p tags?

`simple_format "<span class="required">*</span>"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately -- you can't.  If you check out the source at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format you'll see that the p tags are wrapped around the content unconditionally.

You could create a helper that uses the simple_format code, but modify it to not include the p tags...

Comment: is there an alternative to simple_format? all i want my method to display is `<span class="required">*</span>` and having the HTML interpreted

Comment: well again -- simple_format is only 9 lines long, and if you removed the second, eighth and ninth lines, it wouldn't put the P tags in anymore.

But, I'm not sure what you mean by "having the HTML interpreted"?

Comment: looks like in Rails 4 you will be able to change the wrapper tag like so `simple_format(my_text, {}, wrapper_tag: "div")` but it ain't working for me in Rails 3

Answer (score 11):

You can specify `wrapper_tag` option.

```
simple_format 'Hello', {}, wrapper_tag: 'span'
```

This code will be:

```
<span>Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what you really wanted, but... I ended up doing this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def nl2br s
    split_paragraphs(sanitize(s, tags: [])).join('<br>').html_safe
  end
end
```

**UPD** Or better this:

```
def nl2br s
  sanitize(s, tags: []).gsub(/\n/, '<br>').html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround, if you simply want to get rid of browser-styles:

```
simple_format "<span class="required">*</span>", {}, wrapper_tag: 'p style="margin: 0"'
```

…*hackedy-hack-hack*…