# Rails: how to render HTML inside a link_to block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a nested form following rbates approach: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

I'm also using Twitter Bootstrap.

I'm trying to add an `Add Child` button with an icon. So I modify the `link_to_add_fields` and rename it `icon_to_add_fields`. This is what I have...

```
def icon_to_add_fields(name, f, association, icon_class = '', button_color = '')
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
  id = new_object.object_id
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
  end
  link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn #{button_color}", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")}) do
    "<i class='icon-plus-sign icon-white'></i> #{name}"
  end
end
```

The problem is, instead of rendering `<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add Child` as HTML, my button reads `<i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add Child` on top of it.

So, to "fix" that, I add `simple_format` like this...

```
link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn #{button_color}", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")}) do
  simple_format "<i class='icon-plus-sign icon-white'></i> #{name}"
end
```

Now, the HTML inside the link renders well, BUUUT, there are `p` tags inside, which I do not want.

I'm supposed to end up with something similar to this: `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-white"></i> Add Child</a>`

How can I correct this function to render HTML correctly, but don't output `p` tags?

Comment: You can unescape the html string with raw, h or html_safe, look [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `simple_format` always wrap the results with `<p>` tags. But as stated on an answer to this question, [Rails 3. simple_format do not wrap result in paragraph tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718160/rails-3-simple-format-do-not-wrap-result-in-paragraph-tags), the method is only 9 lines long and can easily be overwritten to not wrap the contents with `<p>` tags by removing some of the lines.
So i believe you can make a `another_simple_format` helper and use it on your `icon_to_add_fields` method and you would be ok.