# Rails: simple_format alternatives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a blog/news site and I am looking for better formatting options than simple_format. I'm happy that simple_format creates paragraphs, for better readability, but I am looking for just a little more. I'd like to give editors an option to create headers over their paragraphs, add links and perhaps a few more basic formatting options.

Simple_format

```
<%= simple_format(@post.body) %>
```

Comment: You're moving into potentially tricky territory here. What's good about simple_format is that it's simple (think limited), so there are only a couple of things people can do, none of which really messes with your layout. Do you want your users to be able to add gigantic headlines to their posts? Do you want them to indiscriminately link outside sites to yours? There are Rails WYSIWIG editor gems out there, but you might want to think about how much power you want to be handing to your users.

Comment: Content editors, yes. Users, no. Users can comment. But content creators will be writing the articles and should be able to format them.

Comment: Kramdown is a great alternative IMHO.

Comment: You can also easily rule out the stuff you don't want it to format: https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb#L75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have one solution but I'm willing to bet you have already searched the page on the helpers [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format)? From there you can scroll down to ":wrapper_tag" which gives you at least some form of customization (minimal at best). It let's you wrap a tag of your choice which is then wrapped by the paragraph tag. I found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718214/6641706). The first response there says "Unfortunately -- you can't...p tags are wrapped around the content unconditionally".

**But**, scroll down on the [same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29669181/6641706) and you'll see that someone created a helper method that might help you.

For the time being, I just stopped using simple format as I'm not making blogs or anything that would need that. Also another tip, maybe you could just use a sanitizer and customize like the response linked above.

Hope that helped! I know that it probably wasn't the answer you were looking for but I guess it's a start.

**UPDATE 7/26 11PM**
Looks like the person in the second article wasn't the first to create a separate helper. I found [this](http://www.kensodev.com/2012/03/06/better-simple_format-for-rails-3-x-projects/) and while it is from Rails 3, it should help you:

```
def simple_format_no_tags(text, html_options = {}, options = {})
  text = ” if text.nil?
  text = smart_truncate(text, options[:truncate]) if options[:truncate].present?
  text = sanitize(text) unless options[:sanitize] == false
  text = text.to_str
  text.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n") # \r\n and \r -> \n
  text.gsub!(/([^\n]\n)(?=[^\n])/, ‘\1<br />’) # 1 newline -> br
  text.html_safe
end
```